# how can i know which button is cliked

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

This is the method execute every time I clicked on any button

```
- (void)menuButtonClicked:(int)index
{
}
```

responder of that method is

```
- (void)onMenuButtonClick:(UIButton*)button
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(menuButtonClicked:)])
        [self.delegate menuButtonClicked:button.tag];
    [self dismissMenuWithSelection:button];
}
```

My question is I want to print first button, second button is clicked in NSLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've everything, you just have to `NSLog` it :)

```
- (void)menuButtonClicked:(int)index
{
    if(index == 1) {
        NSLog(@"First Button Clicked");
    }
    else if(index == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Second Button Clicked");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign `Tag` to every `UIButton` `Object` and then you can use follwing method to get which `UIButton` is `Tapped`

```
- (void)menuButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    UIButton * btnTemp = (UIButton *) sender;

    if([btnTemp tag] == 1){
        NSLog(@"First Button is Tapped");
    }else if([btnTemp tag] == 2){
        NSLog(@"Second Button is Tapped");
    }else if([btnTemp tag] == 3){
        NSLog(@"Third Button is Tapped");
    }
}
```